# Associativity of internal relations in regular categories

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a regular category. Let $X,Y$ be objects of $\mathcal{C}$. A relation from $X$ to $Y$ is an object $R$ of $\mathcal{C}$ together with two arrows $r_1\colon R\to X$ and $r_2\colon R\to Y$ jointly monomorphic. Now consider a relation $(R,r_1,r_2)$ from an object $X$ to an object $Y$ and a relation $(S,s_1,s_2)$ from $Y$ to an object $Z$. Then take the pullback $(R\times_YS, p_1, p_2)$ of $(r_2, s_1)$ and factorize the arrow $\langle r_1p_1, s_2p_2\rangle\colon R\times_YS\to X\times Z$ as a regular epimorphism $q\colon R\times_YS\to I$ followed by a monomorphism $i\colon I\to X\times Z$. We define the composite $S\circ R$ as $(I, p_X\circ i, p_Z\circ i)$.

I want to prove that the composition of relations is associative. So let us consider three relations $(R,r_1,r_2)$ from $A$ to $B$, $(S, s_1, s_2)$ from $B$ to $C$ and $(T, t_1, t_2)$ from $C$ to $D$. I want to prove $T\circ (S\circ R)=(T\circ S)\circ R$. Consider the diagram

[image]

The proof consists in showing that both $(T\circ S)\circ R$ and $T\circ (S\circ R)$ are given by the regular epi - mono factorization of the map $\langle r_1\circ p_1\circ x_1, t_2\circ q_2\circ x_2\rangle\colon X\to A\times D$. But I can't see how to prove that.

Comment: Does it help to recall that if the right square in a rectangle is a pullback, then the left square is a pullback if and only if the outer square is a pullback? $$ \begin{matrix} \bullet &\to& \bullet &\to& \bullet \\ \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow \\ \bullet &\to& \bullet &\to& \bullet  \end{matrix} $$

Comment: I don't know where you got the diagram but there's a mistake : the $q_2$ on the left should really be $q_1$.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Yes, sorry, it's a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider the composition $T\circ (S\circ R)$. We know that $S\circ R$ is given by $(I, p_A\circ i, p_C\circ i)$, and thus to define $T\circ (S\circ R)$ we will need to take the pullback
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}I\times_C T @>\varphi_2>> T\\ @V{\varphi_1}VV @VV{t_1}V \\  I@>>{p_C\circ i}> C.\end{CD}$$

But we know that
$$p_C\circ i\circ q\circ x_1=s_2p_2x_1=s_2q_1x_2=t_1q_2x_2;$$
thus there must be a unique map $q':X\to I\times_C T$ such that $\varphi_1q'=qx_1$ and $\varphi_2 q'=q_2x_2$. Then the exterior of the commutative rectangle
$$\begin{CD}X@>{q'}>> I\times_C T @>{\varphi_2}>> T\\@V{x_1}VV @V{\varphi_1}VV @VV{t_1}V \\ R\times_B S@>>{q}> I@>>{p_C\circ i}> C\end{CD}$$
is exactly the same as the exterior of
$$\begin{CD}X@>{x_2}>> S\times_C T @>{q_2}>> T\\@V{x_1}VV @V{q_1}VV @VV{t_1}V \\ R\times_BS @>>p_2> S @>>{s_2}> C\end{CD},$$
which is a pullback since the two squares are. It follows that the first square of the first rectangle is a pullback as well, and thus $q'$ is a regular epimorphism.

Going back to $T\circ (S\circ R)$, it is defined as the image of the map
$$(p_A\circ i\circ\varphi_1,t_2\circ \phi_2):I\times_CT\to A\times D.$$
Since $q'$ is a regular epimorphism, it will be the same as the image of
$$(p_A\circ i\circ\varphi_1,t_2\circ \phi_2)\circ q':X\to A\times D.$$
But now we have
\begin{align}(p_A i\varphi_1,t_2 \phi_2) q' & = (p_A i\varphi_1 q',t_2 \phi_2 q')\\ & = (p_Aiqx_1,t_2q_2x_2)\\ & = (r_1p_1x_1,t_2q_2x_2),\end{align}which gives the desired expression for $T\circ (S\circ R)$. A similar reasoning shows that $(T\circ S)\circ R$ is also given by the image of that same map.